# Assign value to String from array that has pointers to char arrays

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

I am trying to store in a string (or a char array) the values that come from an array which has pointers to char arrays.
I need this in order to select each char individually so I can store it in eeprom.

_stringsArr contains the pointers to char arrays.

```
Serial.printf("Point 4 %d, value %s \n", _stringsArr[x], *_stringsArr[x]);
String str(*_stringsArr[x]);
Serial.printf("Point 5 %d, value %s \n", str, str);
```

The output of the previous code is

```
Point 4 1073479076, value abcdef 
Point 5 1073422164, value L��?
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I believe you need to use the [`c_str()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/c_str/) member function to get the underlying `char *` of the `String` class.

Comment: I can confirm this, `std::printf` assumes `char*` or `wchar*` as the parameter for `%s`

Comment: I did the following:  `String str(*_stringsArr[x]);
   Serial.printf("Point 5 %d, value %s \n", str, str.c_str());` And the result is `Point 4 1073479076, value ABCDEF `.  `Point 5 1073422164, value 1073446644`

Answer (score 0):

Per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf, `%s` prints a `char*` (c-string), and as Johnny Mopp mentions, you need to call `c_str()` on a `std::string` to access the underlying c-string;